# Darken function for css theming - Error: argument `$color` of `darken($color, $amount)` must be a color

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to add an option to change the site colour. So, I have a color field which is working fine but the problem is I need to change the colour to 10% darker when the mouse is hover. The function darken says the first argument must be a color.

```
Error: argument `$color` of `darken($color, $amount)` must be a color
```

My code is the following:

```
:root {
  --main-colour: #f06d06;
}

$colour-primary: var(--main-colour);


.btn {
    background-color: $colour-primary;

    &:hover {
       background-color: darken($colour-primary, 10%);
    }
}
```

I need the variable --main-colour because this will be used to change the colour in real time.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: I'm trying to replicate this example: https://css-tricks.com/css-custom-properties-theming/ .  The background-color works fine, the only problem is if I try to use the colour with the darken function

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`var(--main-colour)` is an CSS function that is interpolated at runtime (so it will be resolved AFTER the compilation of SCSS).
SCSS is compiled, therefore all its functions are calculated before and doesnt change run-time.

The problem in your code happens because `darken` function requires a valid color to perform calculations on, and during compilation time all it gets is `var(--main-colour)` and not the color itself. (`darken` is an SCSS function, and not a CSS function, so it cannot be changed runtime).

Comment: and what is the solution?

Comment: @ValRob Sadly theres no direct solution to solve this problem in current state. If you need to darken a color in CSS, you are rather looking for a JS-based solution.

Comment: This is the most succinct explanation I have seen on this, and while I don't like that it works this way, it makes complete sense.

Comment: Instead of using var, use $. then you can work around the problem:

`$green: hsl(154, 59%, 51%);

background: darken($green, 10%);`

Comment: @ParsaArvaneh Its worth keeping in mind that css `var` and sass variables (`$`) are fundamentally different. For example you cannot change sass variables in runtime with javascript, you would have to recompile the styles to see the changes.

Answer (score 3):

That problem comes from Bootstrap.

If you are working with a framework like React or angular, remember to import the function before the variables.

```
@import 'functions';
@import 'variables';
```

Answer (score 1):

As already answered, not possible. However, in some cases `filter: brightness(90%);` could be a workaround. More on CSS filters [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp).

Answer (score 0):

In new version You have to import bootstrap variables. if Still error check file patch, it solves after importing bootstrap variables , I was not importing bootstrap variables ,...
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import '~bootstrap/scss/variables';

Answer (score -1):

You need to import the 3 files

`@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
 @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
 @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";`